# Php exntension: undefined symbol: curl_easy_setopt in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, c++

i am writing a php extension, when i run, i got an error:

```
undefined symbol: curl_easy_setopt in Unknown on line 0
```

this is my function included curl

```c++
std::string MyLib::download_file(std::string url) {
    std::string buffer;
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            return "";
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return buffer;
}
```

in header file:

```c++
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

please help me

**This is compiler command and curl version

```
g++ -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic `php-config --includes`  -L/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 -lcurl  -o  main.o main.cpp
```

i tried with:

```
 g++ -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic `php-config --includes`  -L/usr/lib64 -lcurl  -o  main.o main.cpp
```

but it is same

ldd:

```
[root@extension]# ldd myextension.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff550b2000)
libphpcpp.so => /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so (0x00007f6b375b1000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6b372aa000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6b37026000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6b36e10000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6b36a7b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b62e00000)
```

Curl version:

```
[root@extension]# curl-config --version
libcurl 7.19.7
```

Comment: please post the Makefile or compilation command.

Comment: Is it a linking error ? Did u link the library ?

Comment: @cmidi yes, i linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing a `c++` program, and using a `c` library just add this

```
extern "C" {
    #include <curl/curl.h>
}
```

in c++ function names are mangled to reflect the arguments they take, so it makes it possible to overload functions, the `libcurl.so` with `extern "C"` you force the compiler to use c linkage, and hence prevent name mangling.

You also need to link the resulting binary with `libcurl` for that you need to add

```
-lcurl
```

to the compiler command.

**Edit**: I notice that you have this

```
-L/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 -lcurl
```

it's wrong, make it right with

```
-L/usr/lib64 -lcurl
```

- `-L` You specify the search path for libraries.
- `-l` You specify the soname, which will be found at the path specified with `-L`.

Comment: yes, i added ``-lcurl`` when compiler with g++, but it still is same error

Comment: @MrJerry make sure you use `extern "C"` every time you include `curl.h`.

Comment: yes it is. before, it worked when i complier php by hand. after i reinstall php flow https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/ it return above error

Comment: `-L/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 -lcurl` this is wrong, make it right with `-L/usr/lib64 -lcurl`

Comment: @MrJerry why are you using c++?

Comment: Thanks all. f found why. when create share object: ``g++ -shared -o ....``, i was not add ``-lcurl``